# How to keep SFTP connection alive?

Tags: connection, sftp

I frequently connect to an Ubuntu VPS using SFTP from an Ubuntu desktop using the command line. The server disconnects me after a ridiculously short period of inactivity… something like 180 second or so.

**How can I maintain SFTP connection for a longer period of inactivity? (I administer both client and server.)**

Comment: Answered by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607293 ?

Comment: Thank you @user535733 There is no accepted answer, and there are many answers at the linked question. But I will explore, and self-answer if I find a solution there! :)

Comment: The link is to a specific answer that you may find useful.